# MySQL - максимальный размер поля id в Django

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных, django

Использую БД MySQL для Django. Возник вопрос - а какое максимальное значение может хранить в себе поле id, которое создается по стандарту при миграции модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне не изменяет память, то по умолчанию в создаваемой Django таблице MySQL идентификаторы имеют тип int unsigned, а значит могут хранить значения до 4 294 967 295.

Comment: int, но без unsigned. получается в два раза меньше